# Is there a way to seek documentation for VBA, that is not for VB.NET?

Tags: vba, excel, documentation

I'm using **VBA** in **Excel**, and using the almighty Google to find functions, classes, methods for browsing HTML, string manipulation etc. but my question is actually for a possibly very general future usage.

Usually I find Microsoft documentation pages. Sometimes I figure out a way to use them, sometimes not. For example I found the function "Filter" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s(v=vs.90).aspx) for string manipulation which seems to be for VB, not VB.NET however I have trouble running even the example code. I get a "variable not defined" error for "CompareMethod" constant.

I this specific situation I suspect I may need to add some references to my code in order for the compilator to recognize the symbols.

As a different example: I used the function Split (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split.aspx), which seems to be for VB.NET, however it seems to work as intended in my VBA code.

**My Question**: Can someone please not only explain to me what is happening here, but more importantly stir in the right direction by showing, where I can find VB functions and classes documented and their references explained in a way, that allows me to just add them in Excel VBA code?

EDIT: I like to emphasize that I see the *Requirements* part of the description, however I doesn't help me much in Excel, since I can only access libraries through Tools > References, and the names there are quite different then the *namespace*, *module* and *assembly* names on Microsofts' site.

Comment: have you tried googling with `-"VB.NET"`? That should exclude all sites which contain the phrase VB.NET...

Comment: some functions will work similarly but you need some adjustments. For `Filter` function you will use VBA `vbBinaryCompare` instead of VB `CompareMethod.Binary`. to know it you need some more...practice.

Comment: if msdn display "visual basic" or "vb.net" it's not the documentation for "vba" (think of it like another language. C# is not C++, even if in vba, functions have some parts in common with vb). To find vba function I always add "vba" in my search. If you only find "visual basic" instead of "vba" on the first page, take another site then "msdn" for your function

Comment: I happen to have downloaded offline documentations for VBA for Office suite, but I don't remember where, I'll take a look into it and let you know!

Comment: @KazimierzJawor I actually managed to find this one out by searching the "Object Browser" in Excel. I imagine with enough trying I will eventually overcome every obstacle I ever encounter. However sometimes it's just not worth the time investment. That's why I'm asking, if there is a proper documentation or something of that sorts, which allows to find stuff like this. I mean I imagined such a documentation must exists!

Comment: @R3uK That's great news! If you find something I will be much obliged.

Comment: @Lurco : You can download them here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40326

Comment: If you use Google to get more details about info not covered in the Help or other downloaded documentation, I found it more efficient to start the search phrase with the most relevant words "excel vba" (in double quotes) then use the area of interest like "filter", or "string functions". If you need updated documentation from Microsoft add "+microsoft.com". So one complete search phrase would be `"excel vba" string functions "+microsoft.com"`

Comment: Have you tried to use the "Object Browser" in the code window ? That would allow you to find the content of a given reference package (To choose from the list of references that you have entered in tools / references)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go - This is a site I use a lot. It has Functions all over it as well as tons of other VBA useful things. 
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php

This one is to the rest of VBA, Macro's, and other tools for Excel VBA
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/index.php